# Background position bottom in IE8 and IE9 not working

Tags: html, css

I Have used this css in Body

```
body {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    background:#000 url(../images/footer.jpg) left bottom repeat-x;
    color:#fff;
}
```

It is working fine in every browser except IE8 and IE9. I think position of background bottom didn't work in IE8 and IE9.
Is there anything else which can work?

thanks!

Comment: It could be anything, it's hard to tell without a bare test case.

Comment: Kind of hard to test without a live link. Could be as simple as your syntax. Try updating to: background:url(../images/footer.jpg) bottom left repeat-x #000;

Comment: @alex can you give any link of site where i can put my HTMl and CSS to show.. a demo page..?

Comment: There must be another issue. Your code works fine in IE8 / IE9. Please post a relative link or reproduce the bug in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). This is a fiddle of your posted code working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/VgRa5/

Answer (score 1):

In the background shorthand property, the position values come last:

```
background:#000 url(../images/footer.jpg) repeat-x left bottom;
```

It's interesting that your code works perfectly in other browsers, as this is the format for the shorthand property.

Comment: thanks Purmou for response.. but issue is still here.. if you make a HTML page and use this body property it will look fine all browser but IE8 and IE9 (which are buggy with position of background) didn't show it anywhere in page.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set any background image in the `body` element. Rather add a `div` element which wraps all content and set the background image and the position for this `div`.